# Any better way to change CAlayer position without delay while scrollview scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, calayer

Here is my [Vide Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWiPp.jpg). It happens when User quickly scroll my scrollview, My top CAlayer position can't catch on scrollview offset X change. CAlayer delay it position change.

Here is my code
[image]

So is any better way to improve it ?? Thanks

Comment: Can you print `percentage` value and give me the log when it's running?

Comment: I think you should connect animations with `CADisplayLink`. I don't know how. Just an idea.

Comment: @trungduc Here is my link https://imgur.com/a/LjgHO.

Comment: @LalKrishna Thanks, I will tried out

Comment: @StephenChen As I see in the image, sometimes `percentage` value is bigger than 1. Is this ok? What happens if you change `drawsAsynchronously` to `false`?

Comment: @trungduc same result. lol, still delay unlike horizontalScrollIndicator move seamlessly. I found the problem is not the CALayer, it seems the **scrollViewDidScroll** delegate delay the data haha...

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing a frame change of a CAShapeLayer in a UIScrollView - normally there's a delay, unless I use the following code:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:true];
//update your frame etc.
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thx, i will make a try.